# Change default port for PulseAudio (line out, not headphones)

Tags: fedora, configuration, audio, pulseaudio

When I boot, PulseAudio defaults to sending output to Headphones.  I'd like it to default to sending output to Line Out.  How do I do that?

I can manually change where the output is current sent as follows: launch the Pulseaudio Volume Control application, go to the Output Devices tab, and next to Port, select the Line Out option instead of Headphones.  However, I have to do this after each time I boot the machine -- after a reboot, Pulseaudio resets itself back to Headphones.  That's a bit annoying.  How do I make my selection stick and persist across reboots?

Here's a screenshot of how the Volume Control application looks after a reboot, with Headphones selected:

[image: Volume Control, immediately after boot]

If I click on the chooser next to Port, I get the following two options:

[image: Choices for output port]

Selecting Line Out makes sound work.  (Notice that both Headphones and Line Out are marked as "unplugged", but actually I do have something plugged into the Line Out port.)

Comments: I'm not looking for a way to [change the default output device](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/DefaultDevice/).  I have only one sound card.  `pacmd list-sinks` shows only one sink.  Therefore, `pacmd set-default-sink` is not helpful.  ([This](http://www.realitysend.com/log/linux/changing-output-device-with-pulseaudio) doesn't help either.)  Here what I need to set is the "Port", not the output device.  If it's relevant, I'm using Fedora 20 and pulseaudio-5.0-25.fc21.x86_64.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had the same problem (for at least a year now), and the following seemed to work:

Taken from: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164868

Use `pavucontrol` to change the port to your desired one. Then find the internal name of the port with this command:

```
$ pacmd list | grep "active port"
    active port: <hdmi-output-0>
    active port: <analog-output-lineout>
    active port: <analog-input-linein>
```

Using this information about the internal name of the port, we can change it with the command:

```
pacmd set-sink-port 0 analog-output-lineout
```

If you (or someone else with the problem) has multiple cards, try changing the 0 to a 1.

If this works, you can put:

```
set-sink-port 0 analog-output-lineout
```

in your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file to have it across reboots.

Comment: When I try to set-sink-port etc... I get [No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.], how do I change this?

Comment: @aSystemOverload: Which Fedora version? You could also try to to start it manually with pulseaudio --start and see if the `pacmd` command works.

Comment: Apologies for not specifying, but Debian Jessie. The Pulse Audio 'Volume Control' shown by the original poster is working, does that mean a daemon is running, but maybe but a season daemon?

Comment: After so much time at 2:57 AM you saved my life ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped me to configure my headphones as default in Linux Mint 18.3!

Comment: I'm trying to adapt this for use with Ubuntu 22.04. The output of `pacmd list | grep "active port"` shows five active output ports, which all look like `active port: <[Out] HDMI3>` though HDMI3 changes in decreasing priority through HDMI2, HDMI1, Headphones, Speaker. I'm trying to make Speaker the highest priority but `pacmd set-sink-port 0 Speaker` results in `No sink found by this name or index`. I can't use `pacmd set-sink-port 0 [Out] Speaker` because of the space so how can I change the priority? My goal is to have the volume keys on my keyboard control the speaker when it is being used.

Comment: Found buggy behavior with both `pacmd` and the `default.pa` config file directives: `set-default-sink` and `set-card-profile`.   This is on a system with two sound cards (`HDA NVidia` HDMI on GFX card, & `HDA Intel PCH` HDMI on motherboard integrated Intel `i915` GFX) where both use `snd_hda_intel` kernel module driver.  Symptoms: `pulseaudio` fails to set default sink to primary GFX card (Nvidia HDMI), defaulting to onboard SPDIF Intel HDA, ignores both directives `set-default-sink` and `set-card-profile` when given full card name (`alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra3`)

Comment: Workarounds for `pulseaudio` ignoring `set-default-sink` and `set-card-profile` were:  1) Reboot & hope it works (sometimes it fixed the issue, only to arise frequently again next time (maybe some strange race condition with `gdm3` ? ).   
2) Try using `pacmd set-default-sink` with numeric card ID numbers rather than PCIe-bus full names (e.g.: Find card ID with: `pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index:'` ...  Then set default with: `pacmd set-default-sink 0 output:hdmi-stereo-extra3`).  When the kernel & cards are in that state, `pulseaudio` only responded to numeric ID-based commands.

Answer (score -1):

When you opened `pavucontrol`, is your `Line Out` output uplugged?

[image: Line Out (unplugged)]

- Yes: You have your speakers in wrong connector.
- No or didn't help: Good luck, I have no idea what is wrong.

Explanation: Only plugged in port is used as default, if all are unplugged who knows why it's headphones. PulseAudio tests only one connector (Front speakers / green) but outputs stereo in all of them (if you have more than stereo capable card but your PulseAudio is set to stereo only).

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't seem to help.  To answer your question: As I described in the question, Volume Control thinks Line Out is unplugged, but there is actually something plugged in.  As I wrote in the question, "Notice that both Headphones and Line Out are marked as "unplugged", but actually I do have something plugged into the Line Out port."  It seems that the "plugged/unplugged" detection has gone awry.