# Changing audio output from terminal

Tags: audio, output

I have a Xonar DGX card, and I can change the audio output with `alsamixer` by going to the `Analog Output` option and switching between `Stereo Headphones` and `Stereo Headphones FP`. How can I do the same by using the command line?

I've looked up and found about sinks and how they can be switched with `pacmd`, but from what I understand my both outputs are within the same sink, which is my Xonar card.

Comment: If both outputs are within the same sink in PA, they probably will have different associated profiles.

Comment: `amixer` is the commandline version of `alsamixer`

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175930/change-default-port-for-pulseaudio-line-out-not-headphones.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can do this using a number of tools, such as `amixer`, or `pamd`, or `pactl`.

**NOTE:** Your assumption is how I understand things as well. Sinks I equate to actual soundcards (output), and the outputs on them are called ports.

The actual definition from this guide titled [PulseAudio under the hood](https://gavv.github.io/blog/pulseaudio-under-the-hood/):

> **Sink**
>
> A sink is an output device. It is an active unit that consumes samples.
>
> Sink usually runs a thread with its own event loop, peeks sample chunks from connected sink inputs, and mixes them. It also implements clocking and maintains latency. The rest of the world usually communicates with a sink using messages.
>
> The typical sink represents an output sound device, e.g. headphones connected to a sound card line output or on a Bluetooth headset. PulseAudio automatically creates a sink for every detected output device.

#### Example

Here's an example showing how to use `pactl`:

```
$ pactl list sinks |& grep -E "Sink|Ports|analog-ou"
Sink #0
    Ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9900, not available)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, not available)
    Active Port: analog-output-lineout
```

Above you can see my `Active Port:` is currently my soundcard's lineout. Let's change that to the headphones.

```
$ pactl set-sink-port 0 analog-output-headphones
```

And if we check again:

```
$ pactl list sinks |& grep -E "Sink|Ports|analog-ou"
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Sink #0
    Ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9900, not available)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, not available)
    Active Port: analog-output-headphones
```

From `man pactl`:

```
   set-sink-port SINK PORT
          Set the specified sink (identified by its symbolic name or
          numerical index) to the specified port (identified by its symbolic 
          name).
```

#### What if audio device disappears?

In rare cases I've noticed that the audio output device mysteriously disappears from the list of devices. If you find this happens you can easily resolve this by telling Pulse Audio to reload its modules:

```
$ pactl load-module module-detect
```

#### References

- [How can I change the default audio device from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line)
- [Change default port for PulseAudio (line out, not headphones)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175930/change-default-port-for-pulseaudio-line-out-not-headphones)

Comment: Why do you use `|&`? And what is the reasoning behund `analog-ou` instead of `analog-output`? Not that it changes anything, but the output colors look better that way. I also included `|Name:` in the `grep`-Expression to be able to see more easily which Sink is which. You could also add `iec958-stereo-output` and `[Out] ` alongside the analog one for a more complete output including HDMI and digital outputs. My full command would then be `pactl list sinks |& grep -E "Sink |Ports:|Name:|\[Out\] |analog-output:|iec958-stereo-output:"`. Should I post a separate answer including all the details?

Comment: Is is possible that you used this answer to change ports, but no to change sinks?

Answer (score 2):

I used `pacmd` to auto switch sound from pc speakers to hdmi:

```
if grep '^connected$' /sys/class/drm/card0/card0-HDMI*/status ;then             
  sleep 2
  pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
else
  sleep 2
  pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
fi
```

To get the active sound profile:

```
pacmd list |grep 'active profile'
        active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
```

To list all the available output sound profiles supported:

```
pacmd list |grep 'output:'
```

Comment: @Cadoiz `pacmd` was (at 2018) the name of Pulse Audio deamon. I have not checked recently if the deamon name has been changed. Search about Pulse Audio.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Pulse Audio can be installed with one of [`apt-get install pulseaudio-utils`, `brew install pulseaudio`, `brew install pulumi` or `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.pulseaudio` among others](https://bit.ly/3DOTJQR).

I tried to extend your command for listing the output profiles as follows: `pacmd list |grep -E 'Default |module\(s\)|sink\(s\)|source\(s\)|client\(s\)|card\(s\)|sink input|index:|output:' | grep -B2 'output:'` - that way, you will easily see the index of each profile and to what it belongs.

Comment: Unfortunately my result was the same as with other methods: The output seems to change according to console, but not according to the gui util and real sound.
Note that there could be more than one active sound profile   - and you can omit the second grep to also see the "dead" indices.

Comment: [This askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/72076/830570) showed me `pacmd list-sinks`. Analogously, you could use an easier command: `pacmd list-cards |grep -E 'index:|name:|output:'`

Answer (score 2):

All of the other answers here didn't solve my problems as they [don't change necessary parts of the configuration or don't move active streams. This Q/A provides some answers which are fairly complicated](https://askubuntu.com/q/71863/830570). But note that today (as of Jul 15, 2022 on on *Ubuntu 22.04*), it is **much** easier than described in [slm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459246/318461) or [the other ones on that related askubuntu Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/q/71863/830570).

Especially [this answer there](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418802/830570) made me consider an answer here too.

---

### You can just use

> - `pactl list short sinks` and
> - `pactl list short sources`
>
> to get the list of available sinks and sources

(from [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418802/830570)). After that, you can switch with

```
pactl set-default-sink '<the name of the sink from the list>'
```

The [mentioned answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418802/830570) also provides a script to switch/toggle between two different devices.

---

[slm mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459246/318461) a "number of tools, such as `amixer`, or `pamd`, or `pactl`". These can be found in different answers. Here are some references using

- [*the old skillset* of PulseAudio aka `pactl` (by slm)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459246/318461)
- [`pacmd` (by George Vasiliou)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459725/318461)
- [`amixer` (by Chad Skeeters)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477535/318461) (it's ["the commandline version of alsamixer"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459240/changing-audio-output-from-terminal/459725?noredirect=1#comment835019_459240)), but gave me [this commented error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459240/changing-audio-output-from-terminal/459725?noredirect=1#comment1372463_477535). Therefore I only mention it here for reference and the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `amixer`.

```
amixer -c 0 cset name='Analog Output Playback Enum' 0
```

Where 0 in `-c 0` represents the card number.  The last parameter is as follows:

```
0 - 'Stereo Headphones'
1 - 'Stereo Headphones FP'
2 - 'Multichannel'
```

Comment: Unfortunately gives me `amixer: Cannot find the given element from control sysdefault:0`. I used `amixer -c 0` to display all the different options.